# Why USB Tethering goes off after a while?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, tethering, 3g

I use 3G, Android 2.2, LG P500 phone. I've tested it on Windows 7 and Windows XP, the result is the same. After several minutes the connection dies and I need to switch off/on the USB Tethering option to restore the connection.

Comment: I've found solution. I.e. I found how to organize stable internet through my Phone using 3G. It could be done by LG PC Suite, Tools->"Internet Connection Using Your Phone". It works without needing to switch anything in Phone. But I still wondering why simple USB tethering doesn't work.

Comment: I am having the same issue with the mytouch 4g on tmobile-usa. On both my x64 and x86 windows 7 machines the internet connections die after a few minutes of browsing. The network remains active on the phone however. I am not sure how this is being accomplished. The symptoms are identical on both of these machines regardless of whether i tether over wifi or usb. I can however tether to my x64 ubuntu machine and the internet stays active indefinitely. I would very much like to know what is going on here so that I can find a work around for my windows 7 machines.

Comment: If you've found a solution, you should post it as an answer then accept it. This will help future readers of this site who have the same issue find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution. I.e. I found how to organize stable internet through my Phone using 3G. It could be done by LG PC Suite, Tools->"Internet Connection Using Your Phone". It works without needing to switch anything in Phone. But I still wondering why simple USB tethering doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is most certainly due to network restrictions.

For instance 3G connections on Orange (UK) are dropped if you hit it with "too many" requests in a short period of time. This is very easy to do with a PC, just open a dozen tabs on a browser and the 3G connection is dropped.

Comment: is there anyway you know to determine the actual number of requests that is too many? i suspected it was something like that but if i knew how many was too much, then perhaps i could find a way to throttle chrome (or whatever browser) to only request so many things at one time

Comment: I'd say ask the network operator. Thing is some of them  don't actually (officially) support tethering, e.g. Orange UK. So asking might put you on the spot (depending on the guy on the phone, they might not care)

Comment: haha yeah well im on verizon in the us, im pretty sure i signed a contract that states specifically that i will not be using the phone for tethering, so i kind of figured that asking is out of the question. verizon does officially support tethering, but only if you pay $20 extra a month.

Comment: That's exactly why the drop the connection when they see PC like usage :)

Comment: haha i know, i just wish i could find a way around it, i very much need that $20/month, whereas i think verizon will probably be ok without it.